# Problem with changing the size of a JButton within a JxBrowser JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

So i am using JxBrowser and have it added to the JFrame. Now I want to add like multiple buttons to the right side of the browser but it doensn't matter what I try (test1.setSize, or test1.setPreferredSize etc it doesn't change the size).

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzCTQ.png)

The red rectangles in this pictures are examples of the size of the JButtons i want at the right side of the JFrame. Why does the JButton remain that big?

here's the code:

```
    public test() {
    test1 = new JButton("test");
    test1.addActionListener(this);
    browser = new Browser();
    view = new BrowserView(browser);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FOEBot - Gemaakt door Gerrit");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(test1, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
    frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    browser.loadURL("https://www.google.nl/");
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really have a look at the [Layout documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Here you have an example how I solved your problem. I put the `JButtons` into another container which is used as a `BoxLayout`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel mainContainer = new JPanel();
    mainContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();  
    jf.add(mainContainer);

    JPanel browser = new JPanel();
    JLabel browserDummy = new JLabel("Browser");
    browser.add(browserDummy);
    browserDummy.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 200));

    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
    buttonContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    buttonContainer.add(new JButton("Button one"));
    buttonContainer.add(new JButton("Button two"));

    mainContainer.add(browser, BorderLayout.WEST);
    mainContainer.add(buttonContainer, BorderLayout.EAST);

    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.pack();
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

I never did anything with browser programming in Swing so I just used some dummies, but the principle should be the same.

Result:
[image]